# How to get the type based on first params result?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to define the specific object type when user input a custom key?

If this is my data:

```
export const defaultStore = {
a: {
    a1:1,
    a2:'a2',
},
b: {
    b1:2,
    b2:'b2',  
},
c: {
    c1:3,
    c2:'c2',   
}
};

export type StoreState = typeof defaultStore;
```

I will provide a method `setData(key,value):SetData`to change data, it defined like this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

export type SetData<Partial<StoreState>> = (
    key: keyof StoreState,
    value: ValueOf<StoreState>
) => void;

// setData('a',{a1:0})
```

but when user call the method and input the first param like`setData('a',)` ,`{b1:1}` `{c2:'cc'}`are legal input in second param. This can be misleading to users.

Is there any way to give user the correct prompt? it means params like `{a1:3}` `{a2:'aa'}` are legal, other param like `{b1:1}` will get error.

**update:** add Partial, params are optional

Comment: Since you haven't defined `setData()`, and you haven't shown that `setData('a', {a1:0})` actually works (it shouldn't given your definition), this isn't really a [mre].  Could you fix it so that your example code actually demonstrates your issue?  Maybe you want `Partial<ValueOf<Storestate>>` or maybe you mean you need `setData('a', {a1: 0, a2: ""})` or something?  In either case (but you have to tell us which), something like [this](//tsplay.dev/N539VW) might fit your needs, where the call signature is either generic or takes a union of rest args.  Let me know and I can write up an answer.

Comment: it works! thanks for your help~

Comment: my intention is ```Partial<ValueOf<Storestate>>``` and i hope ```setData('a',{b1:0})``` is error. the example of V1 solved my problem perfectly!